# CloudWatch alarm - anomaly detection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

Need to setup an alarm to monitor the total number of Lambda invocations in the environment. Under normal circumstances, the hourly volume  does not exceed 4k, so setting a static threshold around 5k would make sense. However, given the traffic is expected to increase, an anomaly detection alert makes more sense for long term. I played a bit with the configuration and decided on a metric of type SUM to check the hourly figure with Anomaly detection threshold set to 4. This was configured on 18/10. I was happy with the model generated (the size of the band) based on historic data. However, since I enabled the alarm, the size of the band has completely changed (graph attached for reference). Confused why the band size is so different before and after enabling the alarm. The setup configured based on the model generated when I enabled the alarm is not fit for purpose. Any thoughts on this? One option would be to increase the Anomaly detection threshold, but kinda lost confidence in using this type of config.
[image: Graph]

I have an environment with a number of Lambda functions configured. the environment is up for approx 6 month, so plenty of historic data available. What I'm trying to capture is spikes in invocations of the Lambda functions. I have setup an alarm with the following config:

- Metric name: Invocations.
- Statistic: Sum.
- Period: 1h.
- Threshold type: Anomaly detection.
- Whenever Invocations is... Greater than the band.
- Anomaly detection threshold: 4

Comment: We need to see more on how you've set this up behind the scenes - what data source, what formula, what metrics

Comment: I have an environment with a number of Lambda functions configured. the environment is up for approx 6 month, so plenty of historic data available. What I'm trying to capture is spikes in invocations of the Lambda functions. I have setup an alarm with the following config: Metric name: Invocations. Statistic: Sum. Period: 1h. Threshold type: Anomaly detection. Whenever Invocations is... Greater than the band. Anomaly detection threshold: 4

Comment: Updating the question would be best instead of comments :)

Answer (score 0):

I am finding the same. I have a Cloudwatch anomaly detection alarm on the sum of a metric per hour, but it is completely skewed by the fact that the most recent hour bucket is obviously much less than the others until that hour is complete.

Make the Anomaly Detection on it completely useless.